# Angular 8 get "Set-Cookie" header from HttpResponse

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, cookies

I have the following Java Spring REST API method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
    request.getSession(true);
    LoginResponse res = this.authService.login(request);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When called using Postman or from a FireFox browser, I can clearly see the "Set-Cookie" header:

[image]

Yet, when I'm using `console.log` to print the response in Angular, I don't see this header:

[image]

This is the REST call in Angular:

```
this.http.post<Login>(this.url, this.loginRequest, {
  headers: AuthService.getHeaders(),
  observe: 'response',
  withCredentials: true
}).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I did add `withCredentials: true` and `observe: 'response'` to the request call as suggested, and I do get the whole response, but without the cookie.
What I want to do is to get a cookie after a successful login, which will be delivered with any request afterwards for authentication in the server.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your Spring REST API uses Spring Security? Which version of Spring boot / security do you use?

Comment: No Spring Security, nor spring boot. Simple old Spring MVC :)

Comment: Have you tried to use the built-in JS functionality to get the page cookies? (e.g. `document.cookie`) This is most likely a security feature of the browser to prevent cookie stealing from other domains and isn't passed on to JavaScript (along with that some cookie values won't be accessible because they have the `httponly` setting).

Comment: I've tried now, the result is null :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that browsers do not share the cookies to the client if it's not `https`. I had to follow this [guide](https://medium.com/@richardr39/using-angular-cli-to-serve-over-https-locally-70dab07417c8) in order to serve the application in https mode, and then I was able to see the cookie in the server side.