# How to keep original headers from http proxy request in Angular?

Tags: angular, proxy

In order to avoid CORS error I configured a proxy in my Angular application.
The external url it's behind a proxy so I implement a corporate proxy configuration.

This is my proxy.conf.js file

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

var proxyConfig = [{
    context: '/api',
    target: '{{external_url}}',
    secure: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    pathRewrite: {
        "^/api": ""
    }
}];

function setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig){
    var proxyServer = "{{proxyServer}}";
    if(proxyServer){
        var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer);
        proxyConfig.forEach(function(entry){
            entry.agent = agent;
        });
    }
    return proxyConfig;
}

module.exports = setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig);
```

The request works fine, the response it's correct, however the headers that the external url should answer are not present in the proxied response. This headers are neccesary because includes some tokens that need to be used inside the application.

Is there a way to keep the original headers in the proxy response?

angular.json configuration `

```
"serve": {
    ...
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "move-safe:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
    }
}
```

This is how I'm requesting the url inside my app component:

```
corsRequest(){
    this.http.get("/api", {responseType: 'text', observe: 'response'})
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res); //This is the part where the original headers are not present
    });
}
```

Comment: are you using the custom proxy with your httpInterceptors? can you provide full relevant code?

Comment: As far as I understand angular handles the interception just by setting the proxyConfig attribute in the angular.json file. I added the angular.json fragment where it's configured and how I'm requesting the url throught the proxy

Comment: Your options as shown are invalid json..?

Comment: Sorry, the proxyConfig attribute was missing, I edited the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the headers being configured on the server as "secure" with "httpsOnly" flag enabled.

Initializing the server as https the needed headers were returned as expected.

This answer help me to figure it out: [Angular 8 get "Set-Cookie" header from HttpResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504458/4838653)